# Rails: How to reference a path from one Model in another Models Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

This is an easy question, but I am new to Rails. Simply put, I want to use a route from another model (Score) in my Prediction controller. Once a new prediction is made, I want to redirect to the new_score_path but I keep getting an error -

```
 undefined local variable or method `new_scores_path' for #<PredictionsController:
```

I guess I need to somehow reference the Score model in the Predictions Controller but I am not sure how to do this. Here is my create method

```
  def create
    @prediction = Prediction.new(prediction_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @prediction.save
       user = User.find(@current_user.id)
       user.lastcase = user.lastcase + 1
       user.save
       @user = user
       @patient = Patient.find(@current_user.lastcase)
       format.html { redirect_to url: new_scores_path, notice: 'Prediction WAS successfully created.' }
       format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @prediction }
      else
       format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       format.json { render json: @prediction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
  end
```

Many thanks for reading.

EDIT

I tried

```
  new_score_path
```

and it simply routed me to predictions (i.e. in the index.html.erb file). This was in the address
bar

```
   http://localhost:3000/predictions?notice=Prediction+WAS+successfully+created.&url=%2Fscores%2Fnew
```

Comment: `new_score_path`

Comment: Side note: Neither routes nor controllers actually "belong" to a model. The only thing that links them is just convention and how the scaffold generators work. Routes represent the REST API your application provides to the outside and models are just an internal implementation detail. 
Use `rails routes` to see what generated routing helper methods are actually available.

Answer (score 1):

> This is an easy question, but I am new to Rails. Simply put, I want to
> use a route from another model (Score) in my Prediction controller.

You're thinking about it wrong. The controller doesn't belong to a model. Nor does the route. Models are just an internal implementation detail of the application (or at least they should be in the best of worlds).

All the routing helpers generated from `routes.rb` are available into all your controllers and views no matter what they are named.

> I guess I need to somehow reference the Score model in the Predictions Controller but I am not sure how to do this.

Provided you're following the conventions and have declared the route with `resources :scores` you just need to call the correct helper method `new_score_path`. The new action route helper is always `new_singular_path`.

The only actual link between routes and models is that [Rails provides helpers that can guess what route helper to use](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) based on the name of a model and the Rails conventions.

Comment: Thanks for this - see my edit above please. Sorry for being such a help vampire.

Comment: Ah, I did'nt spot that one. You want `redirect_to new_score_path, ...`. `redirect_to` takes the path or a model as a postional argument. Apparently it takes any leftover keyword arguments and makes them into query string parameters - I didn't actually know that.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the documentation, I explicitly gave the path

```
 redirect_to "/scores/new"
```

This solved the problem; I am unsure if this is the correct/good way to do this, but it worked. Happy to be schooled on better solutions if there are any.

Comment: Nope, not the good way. You should use route helper name, `new_score_path`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how the `redirect_to` method is invoked. Instead of:

```rb
redirect_to url: new_scores_path, notice: 'Prediction WAS successfully created.'
```

Try:

```rb
redirect_to new_score_path, notice: 'Prediction WAS successfully created.'
```

**NOTE** The correct route helper is `new_score_path` (in singular).